# A conjecture on crossing numbers related to primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, permutations

For a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$, its crossing number $\text{cr}(\sigma)$ is the number of pairs $\{i,j\}$ with $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that 
$$i<j\le\sigma(i)<\sigma(j)\ \ \text{or}\ \ \sigma(i)<\sigma(j)<i<j.$$
Crossing numbers play important roles in enumerative combinatorics.

**QUESTION.** Is my following conjecture true? How to solve it?

**Conjecture.** Let $p>5$ be a prime. For each $k=1,\ldots,p-1$, let $\bar k$ be the inverse of $k$ mod $p$, that is, $1\le \bar k\le p-1$ and $k\bar k\equiv1\pmod p$. For the permutation $\sigma_p\in S_{p-1}$ with $\sigma_p(k)=\bar k$ $(k=1,\ldots,p-1)$, we have
$$\text{cr}(\sigma_p)\not\equiv0\pmod p.$$

I have verified that $p\nmid \text{cr}(\sigma_p)$ for all primes $5<p<4000.$

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Based on the slow divergence of $\sum 1/p$, I would expect that the event $p\mid \text{cr}(\sigma_p)$ occurs very rarely but infinitely often. Note that $\sum_{6000<p<10^8}1/p<0.77$, so there is a good chance that the first counterexample satisfies $p>10^8$.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun This is likely a fairly minor point, but I noticed the left side of your definition has a $\le$ as the middle inequality, while the right side has an $\lt$. Should they be the same or is there a reason for them to be different?

Comment: I have extended the verfication for all primes $5<p<10640$. I don't think it is reasonable to quote the heuristic argument without considering the speciality of crossing numbers. In  Question 302323 available from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/302323, there is no obvious pattern for the determinant $D_p=\det[(\frac{i^2-\frac{p-1}2!}p)]_{1\le i,j\le(p-1)/2}$ modulo a prime $p\equiv1\pmod 4$, but it can be proved that $p\nmid D_p$ for any prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$.

Comment: John Omielan, I just copy the standard defintion of crossing in combinatorics. You may find this definition in papers on crossing and nesting of permutations.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun: I see it differently. I think it is not reasonable to make a conjecture from very few observations. Unless proved otherwise, we have every reason to believe that $\text{cr}(\sigma_p)\bmod{p}$ is pretty random, in which case you would need a much longer range to test your conjecture. You would need to test until $10^{100}$ or so to make a reasonable conjecture.

Comment: GH from MO, Indeed, I don't know many functions of MathOverflow. I never realized before that I should do sth. other than voting when an answer appears.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun: Thank you, and thanks for accepting my answer on the binary quadratic forms conjectures! I will delete my previous comment as obsolete.